# How to remove Cataloge URL from ubercart

Tags: drupal, ubercart

How to remove 'catalog' from url, for example
my site 
http://[my_site_address]/catalog
shows me all categories in unbercart.

I want to change 'catalog' from url and replace it to 'store'
I try to change it from view but it is not changing. 
Guide me I am new to drupal.

Comment: are you using D6 or D7?

Comment: If you solve the issue, mark the it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a new URL Alias under Configuration with the path module. It's part of Drupal core, and may already be enabled.

For the rest of the catalog (for e.g www.site.com/catalog/1), you should use this Path Auto  http://drupal.org/project/pathauto module to take effect.